# Django Channels [multichat example]: how do I set up admin to enable adding user(s) to a room?

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am attempting to build a custom chat server, based on the following example:

[channels-examples/multichat/](https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples/tree/master/multichat)

So far, I have got the basic code working but now I wish to modify the /admin page(s) to permit one or more users to be added to a room, rather than just have users 'join' a room. I am experienced with Python 2/3 and Flask but fairly new to Django and I have spent hours trying to find clues or relevant code but without much success so far.

It seems that "Admin actions" would be useful, to invoke chat.consumers.chat_join(), also I presume that I need to add a 'user' field to the Room class of chat.models but now I am not sure what to do next. I have studied the offical Django documentation, the example/Channels code itself and many other sites but I would appreciate some help.

There are couple of point to note in case anyone else is in a similar situation:

1. Django Groups (admin) have nothing to do with the channel.Group,
2. A user can currently 'join' a room but that is a very loosely-coupled relationship, that is not recorded in the DB (postgres). I hope to add such persistence later on.

I have been unable to find any related admin. examples such as assigning tasks to a user, which rather surprised me.

Thanks in advance ...

Richard
PS It seems that I can only post one link - apologies for that.

Comment: Think of Room as a table and record every member requesting and accessing. So you can have the clear picture about what to do next. Now do you want to create "Admin enable to chat into that room" Do it by choice field "Enable/Disable=default" And then processing every message in your consumer function feel free to discard message when those particular conditions not met.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I have found my own solution now, after reading [this Django tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Models).

Answer (score 1):

In models.py.Room:

`owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)`

In utils.py.get_room_or_error():

```
username = user.get_username()
if username != str(room.owner):
    raise ClientError("ROOM_ACCESS_DENIED")
```

The ForeignKey usage permits assignment of a user to a room via the admin pages.

Quite simple really, once you know how :-)

I still need to allow 'staff' access but that should be easy.